# Equally spaced navigation links

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create equally spaced navigation links. (Links will be generated dynamically from CMS, so i am not sure how many links there will be)

Another requirement is that first and last links should be at both edges of layout.

I think i am very close, but links are not equally distributed.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/xhtml-lab/pen/OPdbbO

Please suggest any other method or improvements to make the links equally spaced?

```css
    header {
      width: 960px;
      height: 20px;
      background: #f00;
      margin: 0 auto 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px 0px;
    }
    .strip {
      background: rgba(130, 190, 191, 0.95);
    }
    .nav-wrap {
      width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      nav {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
      }
      ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0px;
        display: table-row;
        li {
          display: table-cell;
          text-align: center;
          a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding: 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            &: hover {
              background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
            }
          }
          &:first-child {
            text-align: left;
            a {
              padding-left: 0px;
              &: hover: before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                width: 25px;
                height: 100%;
                left: -25px;
                top: 0px;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
              }
            }
          }
          &:last-child {
            text-align: right;
            a {
              padding-right: 0px;
              &: hover: after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                width: 25px;
                height: 100%;
                right: -25px;
                top: 0px;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<header>
  Header content here
</header>

<div class="strip">
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href>About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href>Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href>Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href>Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href>Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to look into flex box layout property of css https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: flexbox is not supported in IE9

Comment: then use flexbox for everything and an <!--[if lte IE 9 ]><![endif]--> for anything outdated, obsolete and nightmare inducing.